# jQuery simulate Save Image on iOS / Android

Tags: android, jquery, ios

I need to create a button that on click is saving an image, simulating the right click - "Save image as..."

```
$("#frb-download").on('click', function () {

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = frb_image_url; 
    link.download = frb_filename+'.jpeg';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();

});
```

This seems to be good for all the browsers, but not working in iOS / Android.

Here, when I click on the button, it just open the link of the image, while I would need to open the option panel with "Save Image" (the same you get 
by pressing on the image for a while).

But I don't even know if this is possible, I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: It appears mobile support for the `download` attribute is patchy at best: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility. I would lean on the side of 'this won't work', but have no empirical evidence to support that

Comment: Ok, I see ... So I guess the best alternative for mobile is something like writing on the image "Hold down for download"